# -webkit-border-image not applying the image

Tags: html, css, webkit

I was reading an article about `-webkit-border-image` and `border-image`

I try it but it won't show the image. Here is part of my code. Any help is much appreciated

```
h1
{
    border-width: 5%;
    border-image:url("images/frame.png") 25% stretch;
    -webkit-border-image:url("images/frame.png") 25% stretch;
}
```

Here is my h1

```
<h1>Border Practice</h1>
```

Comment: Could you show the h1 HTML please?

Comment: What do you mean it won't show the image? [example](http://jsfiddle.net/xkwfqtz3/)

Comment: It seem your url is not corecct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be an error with the URL I guess, check the below example, it works for me

```css
h1 {
    border-width: 1%;
    border-image:url("https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/border.png") 25% stretch;
    -webkit-border-image:url("https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/border.png") 25% stretch;
}
```

```html
<h1>Border Practice</h1>
```

Comment: Try giving relative paths as possible. Try other combinations also. Check https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp